# failure message system.dmlexception insert failed

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, dml

```
//this is my before insert trigger

public with sharing class Account_Amount 
{
    public Account_Amount(){} 

    public void calAmmount(List<Account> accList){
    AccountDiscount__c mc = AccountDiscount__c.getValues('AllUser');
    for(Account acc: accList)
    {
        Double discount=mc.AcctDiscount__c/100;
        acc.Ammount__c=acc.Ammount__c-(acc.Ammount__c*discount);
    }
    }

}
```

and my test class is

```
@isTest
public with sharing class Test_Acc_Amount
 {
     static testMethod void test1(){

        Account o1 = new Account();
        o1.Name='bhagyashri';

        o1.Ammount__c=1000.00; 

        insert o1;

        Account pAccount=[select Id,Name,Ammount__c from Account where Name='bhagyashri'];
        System.assert(pAccount.Ammount__c==900.00);   

  }
}
```

I'm getting error failure message: `system.dmlexception insert failed` 
and getting code coverage 87 %

Comment: What's the API version of the unit test class? I think you'll need either "@isTest(SeeAllData=true)" or you'll need to insert the values of custom setting in the unit test before inserting the account.  The full error message will tell you what happened (I sense "null object" problems) and which line actually was the problem. See https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000090lvIAA and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm

Comment: @isTest(SeeAllData=true) is works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your trigger code is retrieving a custom setting value.

Which API version is your test class written in? Because current versions default to seealldata=false which means that there won't be any data in the custom settings during the test execution.

Answer (score 1):

it's a good idea to always wrap your DML calls in try/catch blocks like this:

```
try {
    insert / update / delete / undelete statement
} catch (DMLException dmle) {
    System.debug(dmle);
}
```

Doing so will let you know WHY your DML is failing.

Comment: I totally recommend this.